# Does $\log(f(n)) = O(\log(g(n)))$ imply $f(n)=O(g(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics

Let $f(n) = O(g(n))$. Then we know that $\log(f(n)=O(\log(g(n)))$.

Is the converse of this statement also true?

Does $\log(f(n))=O(\log(g(n)))$ imply $f(n)=O(g(n))$?

Let's say $f(n)=n!\   g(n)=n^n$.

Since $n!=O(n^n)\rightarrow   \log n!=O(log n^n)$. This is true.

Now suppose I don't know that  $n!=O(n^n)$. But I know that $\log(n!)=\theta(n\log n)=\theta(\log n^n). $

Now since $\theta$ is symmetric I can conclude that $\log n^n=\theta \log(n!)$

$\log n^n=\theta (\log n!)$ means $\log n^n=O(\log n!)$.

If the converse that I am asking is true then $n^n=O(n!)$. But this is not true.

So this means the converse does not hold.

Am I true?

Comment: For a simple counter example (to the title's statement), let $f,g$ be $n^2, n^3$ respectively.

Comment: Your question already contains a complete answer. We cannot help you unless you are unsure about a specific step. Grading your exercise is your TA's task, not ours.

Comment: Another counterexample: $2^n$ and $3^n$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I just wanted to know whether the conclusion I have reached is correct or not?  I have got it with the counter examples mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @KishanKumar We're not here to check your proof. That would almost certainly never be useful to anybody other than you, since nobody is ever likely to come up with exactly the same proof. If there's a _specific part_ of the proof you'd like help with, ask about that.